# Finding the smallest positive integers such that $\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{k}^{r} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} b_{k}^{r}$, for all $1\leq r \leq N$.

Tags: number-theory

So we are trying to find two sets of positive integers $\lbrace a_{1},...,a_{n} \rbrace$ and $\lbrace b_{1},...,b_{n}\rbrace$, with nomember of one set in the other, such that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{k} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} b_{k}$$$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{k}^{2} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} b_{k}^{2}$$
$$\vdots$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{k}^{N} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} b_{k}^{N}$$
For some integer $r$. I define 'smallest' in the question title as the solution set with smallest value of $\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{k}$.

For example, for $N=1$ the solution is, $\lbrace 3,1\rbrace$ and $\lbrace 2,2 \rbrace$ as there is only one way to sum $2$ and $3$. For $N=2$, I believe the smallest solution is $\lbrace 4,4,1\rbrace$ and $\lbrace 5,2,2 \rbrace$. How can I find solutions for higher values of $N$?

Comment: What do you mean by *"with member of one set in the other"*? Also, do solutions exist for all $N$?

Comment: In its full generality, this is a notorious unsolved problem that goes by the name of Tarry-Escott, or multigrades. Those search terms will get you many hits on the net in general and on MathOverflow and math.stackexchange in particular.